# Ubuntu 16.04 AMDGPU-Pro Not Recognizing Second Graphics Card

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, gpu, amd-graphics-card, dual-gpu

Running Ubuntu 16.04. Installed AMDGPU-Pro driver. I have an MSI Z270 motherboard, with two AMD Radeon RX 470 graphics cards connected.

When I run lspci | grep VGA only one of the two cards displays.
The exact output is:

```
cardinal@cardinal-MS-7850:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] (rev cf)
```

As you can see, only one card is visible. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver software, then restarting.

Does anyone know what I should try next to see the second gpu?

The ultimate goal is to run a driver with OpenCl, as I am trying to run ethminer, using multiple GPU's. I am also not sure if it is maybe it is the OS, and would need to reinstall Ubuntu.